# How would an experienced Ruby programmer rewrite my mini game?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, loops, nested-loops

I'm writing a small guessing game. I'm writing a points calculation algorithm.

I wrote the following, and it works. But I feel like I'm bringing over procedural background into Ruby, or not leveraging Ruby properly.

How would an experienced Ruby programmer approach the problem? You can test the code on [TryRuby.com](http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0) (copy and paste code in the browser interpreter).

```
# g = guesses
g = [{ id: 1, elmer­: 5, roger: 7, outcome: "Roger Win" },{ id: 2, elmer: 5, roger: 1, outcome: "Elmer Win" },{ id: 3, elmer: 4, roger: 8, outcome: "Roger Win" }]
# r = actual results
r = [{ id: 1, elmer: 3, roger: 9, outcome: "Roger Win" },{ id: 2, elmer: 7, roger: 9, outcome: "Roger Win" },{ id: 3, elmer: 4, roger: 8, outcome: "Roger Win" }]
# points table
p = []    
# rules: correct outcome = 1 point, perfect match = 5 points.

# Loop over results.
r.each do |result|

  # Loop over guesses.
  g.each do |guess|

    # Make sure we compare corresponding ids.
    # So, compare result 1 to guess 1, r2 to g2, etc....
    if result[:id] == guess[:id]

      # Init a hash to store score
      score = {}

      # Did they guess the correct outcome?
      if result[:outcome] == guess[:outcome]

        # Correct outcome guessed! Make a score hash, give'em a point.
        score[:id]     = result[:id]  # game id
        score[:points] = 1            # point

        # Was it a perfect match?
        if result[:elmer] == guess[:elmer] && result[:roger] == guess[:roger]

          # Perfect match! Give them 4 points.
          # They already got 1 point for guessing the correct outcome.
          score[:points] += 4
        end
      end

      # Add the score to the points table
      p.push(score) unless score.empty?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing working code. These types of questions may be suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com Please post this there.

Comment: I move this question already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this look to you?

```
g.zip(r).collect do |guess, result|
  points = (guess == result) ? 5 : guess[:outcome] == result[:outcome] ? 1 : 0   
  {:id => guess[:id], :points => points} 
end
```

Note: This assumes g and r are sorted by :id; if not, you can sort prior to doing this =)
Also, I would define: `FULL_SCORE = 5` and `CORRECT_OUTCOME_SCORE = 1`

Comment: Thanks. Would you consider adding your answer on Code Review? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40416/small-guessing-game-in-ruby